# Showing Bullet in Board in Viewcontroller, when called from TableViewCell (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**What I want to do:** I want to show a Bottom Card with Bullet in Board (a pod), like in this video: https://youtu.be/iSMgOUej2C0 . But I want to add it to a TableView. So when I tap a button on any TableViewCell, the bottom card should show.

**Here is my code:**

```
import UIKit
import BLTNBoard

@IBAction func settingsButton(_ sender: Any) {
        gotosettings()
    }
    
    private lazy var boardManager: BLTNItemManager = {
        
        let item = BLTNPageItem(title: "Settings")
        item.actionButtonTitle = "Delete Post"
        item.descriptionText = "To delete your post, you should press that button above"
        
        return BLTNItemManager(rootItem: item)
        
    }()

func gotosettings(){
        boardManager.showBulletin(above: popularViewController())
        print("did it")
    }
```

**The problem:** The basic Bulletin Board code works fine, but my biggest problem is in the `func gotosettings()`. The app does crash, once I press on the button. The `popularViewController`is the ViewController where the TableView is in.

If I put `self` in there, Xcode tells me, that the TableViewCell is not a ViewController.

Any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Comment: you can't open ViewController from cell, to open ViewControler just grab cell click event in currently loaded ViewController and and open Settings

Comment: @PratikPrajapati but I want this to happen, only if a specific button in the cell is clicked

Comment: you can do same on button click method also, post your code where you implement tableview if possible